# Quartz.Net dependency injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I see a lot of solutions here but they area already outdated. Is there a new approach? It's something about the Ijobfactory.

```
public class JobBase : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public JobBase(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Create fake httpcontext
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
            new HttpRequest(null, "[localhost]", ""),
            new HttpResponse(new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream())));
    }

    public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote a post about it a while back. You don't mention what's outdated about what you found but here's a link in case it's useful: http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2012/07/23/creating-a-custom-quartz-net-jobfactory/

Comment: Iwas referring to the `code`public class NinjectJobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

        public NinjectJobFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
        {
            this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            return (IJob)this.resolutionRoot.Get(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
            this.resolutionRoot.Release(job);
        }
    }`code`, Get/Release doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, you can actually use dependencyresolver to implement a class in the quartz class. It worked for my project.